# There is a file on my mac I cannot delete, even through Terminal

Tags: software

There is a file on my Mac and is sucking my storage and it is showing a prohibit sign on it and I cannot delete it. I cannot delete in Terminal either.

I was just trying to download the old Mojave software on the Mac but it didn't go as planned. It wasn't opening on my Mac so I tried to delete it. I kept it in the trash for many weeks and today I tried to delete it, but it wasn't deleting. I tried to delete it with Terminal, but it didn't work and I am wary because I don't want anything to happen to this laptop.

[image: This is the update software that I tried to delete]

Comment: Where is exactly this file? You can move it in a terminal windows and you have the exact string.

Comment: Could you show the command in terminal that you tried?